# Sublime PHP Linter Executabe Path on Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, sublimetext3

How to get Sublime Linter shows PHP errors when i do not have PHP installed on my local machine. I am using Vagrant for development and PHP is installed there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can still install the [plugin](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-phplint)

on mac do `brew install homebrew/php/phplint` or [see the download page](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/download.html)